# Get new instance of session scoped bean with other name

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2

I have a session scoped bean for a UI to edit some data. It is annotated with @Named and @SessionScoped and all runs in JBoss 6.2. Now I got the requirement for a nearly similar edit UI. The problem is that the two UIs can exist in parallel. So for a perfect reuse it would be nice to create a new instance of the bean with another name. Unfortunately I have no clue how to do this in a clean CDI way.
I don't like it so much to inherit from the bean and give another name. This was one of my ideas.
Another idea was to implement in the managed bean only the business logic and keep the data encapsulated from them and set the data object inside the managed bean when it is needed in the specific context. But maybe there is another CDI way with producers or something?
Changing the scope of the bean to ViewScope makes no sense in my case.

Thanks 
Oliver

Comment: I try the approach to reuse the code of other beans by instantiating them in a new managed bean in @PostConstruct. To inherit and give a new name is not a good idea and leads to problem with cdi to choose the right instance.

Comment: why not BeanB extends BeanA?

Comment: In this case it is not clear for CDI which instance to inject. BeanA oder BeanB. I am also not a big fan of inheritance. Only if it makes absolute sense.

Comment: i meant something else. lets say your Base Class called User(only attributes, setter and getter), then you creates 2 different Beans which extends this class: BeanA extends User & BeanB extends User. i have to mention that i am not an expert of CDI, but this way should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But maybe there is another CDI way with producers or something*

Indeed, you *could* use a producer.

Kickoff example:

```
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean {

    @Produces
    @Named("foo")
    @SessionScoped
    public SessionBean getAsFoo() {
        return new SessionBean();
    }

    @Produces
    @Named("bar")
    @SessionScoped
    public SessionBean getAsBar() {
        return new SessionBean();
    }

    // ...
}
```

*(method names are free to your choice)*

Usage:

```
@Inject
@Named("foo")
private SessionBean foo;
```

```
@Inject
@Named("bar")
private SessionBean bar;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's nice and increases my internal CDI library :)

Comment: Is it possible that CDI creates the instances of SessionBean? If new operator is used the injections inside SessionBean probably I have to retrieve and set by myself.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to pass injected members of SessionBean to the constructur of it in the producing methods.

Comment: If you want to let CDI create instances, then don't use a producer, but just subclass the bean.